# Start chrome without reloading the pinned tabs

Tags: google-chrome

I have about 5-6 pinned tabs, e.g. Gmail, facebook, stackexchange, calendar, etc.., and every time I start Chrome, the browser tries to reload all those pinned tabs. This takes my bandwidth and slow me down on the web I really/actually/newly want to use Chrome to open.

How can I start Chrome browser without loading the pinned tabs? Is there anyway to configure it to load the cached content from the last opened time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to do this via settings, as [mentioned in the bug tracker](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=105666).

You can get extensions that will handle lazy loading of tabs, e.g. [Lazy Tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lazy-tabs/aabgbgciohhaogajcnacpgilhmacdahc?hl=en)

(I haven't tested that particular extension, just the first one that came up . . . )