# Is it possible to disable tab pinning in Chrome? Or prevent pinned tabs from loading when I open Chrome, until I click on them?

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, google-chrome-devtools

I use a productivity extension that can be bypassed via pinned tabs on Chrome launch.

So I'd like a way to disable pinned tabs, or alternatively prevent pinned tabs from loading when Chrome opens, at least until I click on them.

From doing some searching I've seen Firefox has a way of doing this via "browser.sessionstore.restore_pinned_tabs_on_demand". I looked for a similar setting in the chrome://flags but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Start chrome without reloading the pinned tabs](https://superuser.com/questions/625981/start-chrome-without-reloading-the-pinned-tabs)